# Magento 2 change static content folder

Tags: magento, magento2, static-content

Is it possible to rename static content folder? f.e from `../pub/static` to `/pub/statix`

I saw 'base url for static view files' setting in the admin panel, but if I set it to `{{secure_base_url}}/statix/` and re-deploy it, magento won't create that folder and I'll receive pages without css etc. URL will point to the statix, but there won't be that directory

Or maybe I could deploy that content to `statix` folder to make the urls work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the paths of static directories. It is an absolute path and will automatically generate every time you redeploy the site.